# How to remove top margin when element is empty?

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML structure:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
}
small {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
small + span {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p>content</p>
<small>tags</small>
<span>edit</span>
```

All fine. Sometimes `<small>` element is empty. Something like this:

```
<p>content</p>
<small></small>
<span></span>
```

In this case, I want to remove the `margin-top` of `<small>`.

Is that possible using **pure CSS**? It should be noted I don't want to use JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using a combination of `:not` and `:empty` pseudo-classes.

```
small:not(:empty) {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation taking a simple selector *X* as an argument. It matches an element that is not represented by the argument. *X* must not contain another negation selector. -[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

---

> The `:empty` pseudo-class represents any element that has no children at all. Only element nodes and text (including whitespace) are considered. Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether an element is considered empty or not. -[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

Comment: Yes, I knew it before asking, but actually the most of my users use IE7 `:-(` and it doesn't support `:not()`

Comment: Well, in that case you probably need some javascript, is that an option?

Comment: I reserved it *(using js)* as the last option.

Comment: If you're also looking for a javascript solution (I think you will), please add the tag.

Comment: Actually I solved my problem by other way ... I completely changed HTML structure. So this question isn't valid for me anymore and I don't need any js code. thank you `:-)`